# Changing the color of a random div

Tags: javascript

There is a playing field with 25 div. By clicking on the "Play" button, a random div should turn blue.
By clicking on a div with blue color, it should be repainted in green.
If there was no click, after 2 seconds from the moment of tanning with blue, it should be repainted in red.

At my click, the green lights up, and after a while it turns red.
What and how to change to fulfill the above conditions?

```
const duel = ['duel1', 'duel2', 'duel3', 'duel4', 'duel5', 'duel6',
            'duel7', 'duel8', 'duel9', 'duel10', 'duel11', 'duel12', 'duel13',
            'duel14', 'duel15', 'duel16', 'duel17', 'duel18', 'duel19', 'duel20',
            'duel21', 'duel22', 'duel23', 'duel24', 'duel25'];


        let setBlue = (rancelBlue) => {
            const randomNumber = duel[Math.floor(Math.random() * 25)];
            rancelBlue = document.getElementById(randomNumber).style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
            setTimeout(setBlue, 2000)
            setTimeout(()=> document.getElementById(randomNumber).style.backgroundColor='red',2000)
            };


        let setGreen = (e) => {
            if (e.target.style.backgroundColor === 'blue')
                e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
        };

          <div>            
                <div>
                    <button onClick={setBlue}>Play</button>
                </div>            
                        <div onClick={setGreen} >
                                <25 div></div>          
                        </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: setTimeout returns a timerID which can be used to cancel the call. You can capture this ID and in the setGreen function call the clearTimeout function to prevent setting the div to red. Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: not sure I got it right the problem, but you need the green color to remains or what?

Comment: You understood correctly. I need green color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a background check for blue color in the setTimeout callback. If the background color is blue, only then set the color to red.
And I don't see necessary in two call setTimeout, because both working in two seconds.

```
    let setBlue = (rancelBlue) => {
      const randomNumber = duel[Math.floor(Math.random() * 25)];
      rancelBlue = document.getElementById(randomNumber).style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
      setTimeout(()=> {
        if (e.target.style.backgroundColor === 'blue') {
          document.getElementById(randomNumber).style.backgroundColor='red'
        }
        setBlue()
      },2000)
   }
```

Comment: Where can I insert an event "e" ? If i change the variable "rancelBlue" on function и вставлю "e" в качестве аргумента, то вся констррукция разрушится